# Auto click on child element with random ID

Tags: javascript, html, automation

I'm a complete javascript noob and I'm trying to automatically click a button inside a div.

```
<div id="KB_3383878" class="td button-visible">
<button id="KB_1532704" class="inputsubmit">Search</button>
</div>
```

The numbers after KB_ are changed randomly each time the button is clicked. I am ***not*** able to click based off the `inputsubmit` class as there are 3 identical buttons, of which 2 are hidden and they rotate which one is visible after x clicks, and the `inputsubmit` class is also rotated between `inputsubmit` and `enterclass`.

So I have to find the child element of the div with the `button-visible` class.

The JS script I've tried using so far has no effect what so ever:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('button-visible'); 
    var children = parent.children[0]; 
  
  
    setInterval(function(){
        parent.button.click();
    },1000);
};
```

Comment: Why `parent.button`? What is `parent.button`? Why did you name the variable `children` when there's only one child in it?

Comment: Have a look at `.querySelector()` which works with CSS selectors (e.g. `div.button-visible button.inputsubmit`)

Comment: The mentioned selector matches every `<button>` that has the class `inputsubmit` and is a child of a `<div>` with the class `button-visible`. It's the same what your script tries to do -> `const visibleButton = document.querySelector("div.button-visible button.inputsubmit");`

Comment: Hey Andreas, thanks for the quick responses. I edited the OP - I forgot to mention inputsubmit switches between ```inputsubmit``` and ```enterclass```.

Comment: `.querySelector()` uses CSS selectors. Adjust the selector to match both combinations. If there only ever is one "active" button then this should work.

Comment: I copied Karan Singh's example, which is pretty much the same as you're recommending me to do. Sadly this didn't work either, even after using ```document.querySelector('.button-visible button');```. Maybe I should've mentioned this is for a Greasemonkey script, I just assumed it was plain JS "injection".

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referring to the wrong var. `parent.button.click()` should be referring to `children` (which I would name `firstChild` or something).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I changed the script to ```window.onload = function(){
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('button-visible'); 
    var child = parent.children[0]; 
  
  
    setInterval(function(){
        child.click();
    },1000);
};``` but it still does not do anything.